# Matrix of pairwise cosine similarities from matrix of vectors

Tags: pandas, data, numpy, cosine-distance

I have a matrix of 200d vectors stored as follows:

$ X = \begin{pmatrix} \text{id}_1 & 0.5 & -2 & \dots & 10
                \\    \text{id}_2 & -4 & 6 & \dots & -0.3 
                \\     \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots 
                 \\    \text{id}_{N} & 0.3 & 6 & \dots & -0.1 \end{pmatrix}$

The id is a number that identifies what the vector refers to in the particular dataset. Ideally, I would like to construct a new datastructure $Y$ such that I can supply two IDs $\text{id}_i$ and $\text{id}_j$ and find the cosine similarity between the corresponding vectors.

In case it is important, $N=8000$ for this dataset.

My original plan was to use sklearn's `cosine_similarity` function to return a matrix of similarities. However, I don't see how I will be able to keep the ID tages if I do that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This will create a matrix. Rows/Cols represent the IDs.
You can check the result like a lookup table

> *i.e. (ID1, ID91) - Can look at either (0,90) Or (90, 0)*

```py
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
from numpy.linalg import norm

x = np.random.random((8000,200))
cosine = np.zeros((200,200))

for i in range(200):
    for j in range(200):
        c_tmp = np.dot(x[i], x[j])/(norm(x[i])*norm(x[j])) 
        cosine[i][j] = c_tmp

pd.DataFrame(cosine)
```

[image]

*Not an optimized code*.